# When the original author of the question tries to close it, does it still require 4 more votes?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close, original-poster

When the original author of the question tries to close it, does it still require 4 more votes?  It would make sense just to close the question if the request came from the original author.

Comment: possible duplicate of [allow question asker to close own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-asker-to-close-own-question)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this CW on SO

- [Etiquette for closing your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions)

Specially this quote (by Euro Micelli)

> The way I look at it, these questions and answers are not just for you but for anybody who might have the same question in the future. Just because an answer works for you now, it doesn't mean necessarily it will work for someone else in the future.

Comment: It looks like my question is going to win the tumble weed badge.  I would rather close it because I was explaining the wrong cause for my problem.

Comment: You can delete it.

Comment: I have been using the site for long time and just saw that feature.  Like my grandpappy said "If it were snake, it would have bitten you right in the ass!"

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I've wanted to move a few of my questions here to Meta, but I need at least 4 other people to help (or a mod).

However, there are a few issues that would need to be worked out should that user decide to open the question back up. If the owner closes their own question by themselves, should they have the power to open by themselves? If so, what if there are already close votes - closing and reopening would effectively zero out the votes. Maybe if a question is closed by X people (say 2 people + owner) then it would have to be opened up by X people?

In any case, there are tricky edge conditions to be aware of, but I think that if you can delete (and undelete) your own content, then you should be able to close and open it as well.