# Should my vote to "close as off-topic" transfer my own question immediately?

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When the OP votes to close their own question as “belongs on …”, immediately migrate the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25399/when-the-op-votes-to-close-their-own-question-as-belongs-on-immediately-m)

Sometimes, I realize that a question I've asked on one site may be more suitable for another (for example, `writers` instead of `english`). If I vote to close my own question as off-topic (and specify the more appropriate site), I still have to wait for 4 other votes (or moderator action).

If I vote on my own question, wouldn't it be useful for the closing and transfer to become effective immediately?

Comment: I think I've seen this somewhere before...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a reasonable idea. Though I would limit it to a minimum rep and possibly only allow one migration of the question by the OP (to avoid them ping-ponging it all over the place).

In the meantime, you can flag your question for moderator attention and ask for the transfer to happen. This is better than waiting, as if any 2 closers do **not** select to migrate, the question will not get migrated.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't sound unreasonable to me. Just a couple "devil's advocate" notes:

1. You can already delete and repost, if you've not gotten any answers.
2. It's possible that people who would use this might not be the best persons to decide where it should go, so the community vote might still be desireable.
3. You wouldn't want people to use this as a way to ask questions on a site they've been banned on. (from Troyen in the comments, below)

Comment: #1 kind of makes #2 pointless -- there's no reason to block migrations on the theory that "they might pick the wrong site" if they can just go manually post on that site anyway

Comment: Possibly the ability to migrate should be dependant on a minimum rep on both sites?

Comment: You'd also want to make sure the question asker isn't banned on the site they choose to migrate to.  (I don't know if this is checked when the community votes to migrate.)

Comment: @Michael They can only do that if there are no answers. I don't violently disgaree otherwise.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Well, then they can skip the "delete" step and go straight to "repost". And they do, all the time

Comment: @Troyen Excellent point. I've added it.

Comment: @Michael By that logic, why have Migrate at all?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think you're misunderstanding; migrating is great, because it keeps all the history the post has built up. My question is, why restrict migrating at all? If the user can already do it the wrong way (manually reposting), why not let them do it the right way (migrating)? Obviously don't let them migrate if they're question-banned on the other site or something, but they shouldn't need some arbitrary rep amount on the target site or to get other users to vote as well or anything -- they don't need that stuff to just ask on the other site, so they shouldn't need it to migrate

Comment: @Troyen It is, the question closes as off-topic instead

Comment: @Michael If they do it the wrong way now, they'll continue to do it the wrong way then. But note I don't oppose this; I just think there are some things to keep in mind with it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So the theory is "they'll probably do it the wrong way, so let's not even let them do it the right way"? I'm trying to head it off now because good ideas get shut down all the time for nonsense reasons

Comment: @Michael Your comments seem to be assuming I'm opposed to this idea, which I am not.

Comment: @AndrewBarber No, they're assuming that someone will read this and think "he's got a point, we need to pile restrictions on this". Or worse, ["clearly this is too dangerous to implement at all"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78213/145982)