# Askers should be able to close their own question as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Okay, take this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/which-programming-language-feature-would-you-eliminate-and-why

I found out that there was essentially a duplicate question of mine, but specified in very different terms than the question I asked. Therefore, to aid future searchers or search engines, I don't want to delete the question -- people searching using the phrases I used should be able to find the duplicate question. But people shouldn't be allowed to post to my question either, because it is a duplicate.

However, there's no way to really tell the engine that the question should be closed as a dupe.

If the community thinks that the question is not a dupe, then one could use the same 5 vote reopen scheme used for current closures.

(For the record, I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-asker-to-close-own-question) which is similar, but what I'm looking for is more specific in that I think the only valid closure reason should be duplication)

Comment: Does all that stuff really matter on "Programmers"? I thought that was the Wild West?

Comment: I'm confused by "there's no way to really tell the engine that the question should be closed as a dupe". Can't you vote to close?

Comment: @Peter, [this is not 'nam: this is Stack Exchange. There are rules.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiQmQhA-OrM#t=0m57s)

Comment: @Mark - +1 for the dude video ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you have 250 reputation you can vote to close your own questions, which will also show a number beside the close link, encouraging other people to help you (as well as in the 10k tools). Otherwise just post a comment or flag it for moderator attention (diamond mods can close a question without waiting for other votes).

I don't think you should be able to close your own question as a duplicate in one vote, as just because another question solves your problem, doesn't mean it's asking the same thing as your question.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP be the perfect person to know whether a question is a duplicate? IMHO it does make sense to make the close vote of the OP final.