# If a asker votes his own question closed as duplicate, shouldn't that vote be binding?

Tags: feature-request, voting, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow question askers to close their own questions unilaterally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally)

Typically, when close votes start accumulating on a question, this triggers a negative response from the asker, arguing against the closure. Other times, however, the asker agrees with the close reason and, given enough reputation, votes to close the question hisself.

This is what happened to me today, when [I asked a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081946/why-does-console-readline-have-a-limit-on-the-length-of-text-it-allows), and perhaps unsurprisingly it was found to be a duplicate. Note I was the second user to close as dupe (the first found the dupe in the first place.)

Shouldn't this be treated as a binding vote? If I, the asker, agree that my question has been asked in the past and close to vote as duplicate, why do I need <s>four</s> three other people to validate the closing? This seems especially useful with duplicates, which are worth keeping, unlike other close reasons where deletion is more appropriate. On sites such as SO, suffering from big-city problems, this means the community can move onto other, fresher questions faster.

Comment: Law of StackExchange #129: questions about dupes are dupes.