# Proposal: let authors close their own questions

Tags: feature-request, review, answers, vote-to-close

Currently, an author of a question can delete his own question or "vote" for closing.

Sometimes it happens to me that I ask a question and then I realise I was doing some silly mistake.

When this happens, I normally then edit the question and explain the error. For example, [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595694/iptables-doesnt-filter-my-ssh-failed-logins-any-more) I explain that the `hitcount` parameter in iptable counts the number of connection attempts, not the individual password attempts.

Still I don't want to delete the question. This error can happens to other people, so while I don't need any more answers to the question, also I don't want to close it.

Currently I am forced to "vote" to close it, and give some nonsense reason for closing it.

I propose that for question authors there could be a more direct "close" action that closes the question directly, or at least that this is implemented for recent or no answers own questions.

Comment: Rather than editing that in to questions, you should answer your own question and then accept it. This signals to others that a correct solution was given.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you can self-answer and accept that.

Comment: Expanding on the comments: you're using close votes incorrectly there, which is a good reason why we don't want authors to be able to unilaterally close their own question. Not everyone understands that "closed" means "this is an inappropriate question for the site that should be edited or *deleted*." If you've found the answer, post an answer.

Comment: This is very related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally but is old and was only implemented for duplicates.

Comment: The removal of a question should be limited to contributions that cannot be salvaged.  Asking numerous questions then deleting them will only result in the privilege of submitting more questions to be automatically suspended.

Comment: Adding on to @MarkKirby's comment:  I've also seen that editing your questions like that often results in vandalism, like:  "jblaskfjjjdkddddblaaaaaargh fixed fixed fixed thx fixed" in the body and title, which then forces the 2Ks to revert that and explain why.  This way it's easier.  Do you have any other reasons?

Answer (score 12):

A post is usually closed for a reason:  It might be off-topic, unclear, a duplicate, etc.  Closing a post just because you do not want any more answers is not the way to go; if you've found an answer that solves your problem, and you don't need another, you can just answer your own question, and accept it to show people that you have solved it.